# Оплата подписки в телеграм боте python

Tags: python, telegram

Мне нужно сделать бота, который будет отправлять ссылку на оплату подписки, и при оплате переправлять пользователя в другой бот, который закрыт для других. А так же он должен проверять, если закончилась подписка, то он напоминает об этом пользователю и выкидывает его из бота. Как мне лучше реализовать оплату и проверку подписки? Я читал про Freekassa api. Но не нашел, как проверять наличие или отсутствие подписки. Подскажите, как лучше реализовать? Или пришлите уже готовый пример, где реализована данная функция.

Comment: встроенная оплата в телеграм https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/payments_example.py . Тест: @ShopBot

Comment: А есть ли идеи как проверить срок подписки?

Comment: допустим человек оформляет подписку 01.10.2020 на 6мес. в БД пишите id и окончание даты подписки. sheduler'ом рассылайте по нужным id нужное сообщение

Comment: А без БД нет вариантов?

Comment: Текстовый файл)

Comment: Не, я имел ввиду может в самой библиотеке можно обратиться по id к информации?

Comment: Библиотека лишь даёт вам удобный доступ к апи

Comment: А что на счёт подключения пользователя к закрытому чату? Есть идеи?

Comment: Отправлять ссылку от бота который принимает оплату, только после успешной транзакций?

Comment: Но ведь канал приватный. И тогда оплативший подписку человек сможет переслать эту ссылку для других пользователей. Можно как-то это избежать?

Comment: У частных каналов ссылка-приглашения может быть изменена. Возможно через какой-нибудь метод, доступный боту